# I do not find Git Version Control interface in my CPanel. Need it badly for auto deployment

Tags: git, cpanel

I donot find GIT in my CPanel. All I find is how to configure GIT in cpanel with your repositories, but I donot find how to put GIT there in the first place if its not found.

I am using A2Hosting with terrible customer support who never pickup my calls or respond to my chats.

[image]

Can someone please guide me on how I can get Git installed/working in my cpanel please.Thanks.

Comment: Requires cPanel version 72+. What version do you have at the hosting?

Comment: I guess it is 70.0.68. Need to check if I can upgrade it myself. Please let me know if you know a way to do it

Comment: If you're on shared hosting, you're not able to update it, although you probably can if you're on a VPS. Since 70 is EOL, if your host isn't able to update it, you should find a new host, since the version that's running will have security vulnerabilities.